# Multistage build exec go file not found in scratch

Tags: docker, go, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm new to Docker and I have some noob questions. I've followed [this](https://snyk.io/blog/containerizing-go-applications-with-docker/) tutorial to improve Docker files. The single build works fine, but the multistage fails when I use `scratch` image.

The Docker file is:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

##
## STEP 1 - BUILD
##

# specify the base image to  be used for the application, alpine or ubuntu
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS build

# None root user
# RUN addgroup -S qcheckgroup && adduser -S qcheck -G qcheckgroup

# USER qcheck

# create a working directory inside the image
ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /app

# copy Go modules and dependencies to image
COPY . .

# download Go modules and dependencies
# RUN go mod download

# compile application
RUN go build .


##
## STEP 2 - DEPLOY
##
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /

FROM scratch

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build app/query_check_span /

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "/query_check_span" ]
```

The build process works fine `docker build -t qcheck:multi -f .\Dockerfile.multi .` but when I try to run the container with `docker run qcheck:multi` I get the following error: `exec /query_check_span: no such file or directory`.

It looks that the problem is that scratch image is unable to execute the compiled go program. I confirm that when I've change the image to `apline` for example.

Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong? How could I run the container using scratch image?

Comment: Several other similar questions suggest building with an environment variable `CGO_ENABLED=0`; for example ["no such file or directory" with docker scratch image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106186/no-such-file-or-directory-with-docker-scratch-image).  If you have a dynamically-linked binary at all you won't be able to run it in a `FROM scratch` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build stage, you should `RUN go build -o ./query_check_span` instead of `RUN go build .`. That command will output the binary file which has the name `query_check_span`.